# Where can one find the FULL list of allowable values for directionalHint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

All I can find in the documentation is the standard four options.
"topCenter", "bottomCenter", "leftCenter", and "rightCenter".

But in one example ([custom-hover-card](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/e71e7a2d057169f3eee57a3194da2275cb2df1bc/view-samples/custom-hover-card)), I see an option that isn't found elsewhere (rightBottomEdge). I do believe there was also a video, Chris Kent presented one time, showing a much larger list of options, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is full list of available values for directionalHint?:

[image]

**Reference**: [SharePoint Lists custom formatting – Hover cards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bO2L3eJoT2Y&t=16m50s) - video presented by Chris Kent

Comment: Nice screenshot . These values seem to come from the Fluent UI Callout component: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/callout

Comment: FYI: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/pull/8400) to get these added to the documentation

Comment: @theChrisKent Many thanks for fluent UI documentation link & pull request, very helpful!

Comment: Thanks Chris, for all you do for formatted lists!